# Does the presence of magnetic monopole break the time reversal, or does its magnetic charge flip (more naturally)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, time-reversal-symmetry, magnetic-monopoles, cpt-symmetry

It is often said that the presence of magnetic field breaks the time reversal symmetry (see Sakurai quantum mechanics book p.285), because the Lorentz force law shows
$$
\vec F = q(\vec  E + \vec  v \times \vec  B).
$$
And time reversal flips
$$ \vec  v \to - \vec  v$$
but the static $ \vec  B$ field does not flip under time reversal.

However (as Sakurai book also stated), if we take into account that $ \vec  B$ is generated by the electric current $\vec j = e \vec{v}$ so that the $ \vec  B$ also flips sign because $\vec j = e \vec{v}$ flips sign. Then we have under time reversal:
$$
\vec F \to \vec F, \quad e \to e,   \quad q \to q,  \quad \vec{v} \to - \vec{v},  \quad \vec  E \to \vec  E ,  \quad \vec  B \to -\vec  B.
$$
So the Lorentz force law  obeys time reversal symmetry !

### question

Now suppose we have magnetic monopole in our world (due to that the $U(1)$ gauge theory is compact), then the magnetic field $\vec  B $ may not be generated by the electric current $\vec j = e \vec{v}$ alone. So my question is:

- Does the magnetic monopole generate $\vec  B$  that breaks the time reversal?
- Or does the magnetic monopole charge $q_m$ flip sign under the time reversal?
  $$
  q_m \to - q_m?
  $$
  If so, how do we understand this fact alone better? (any deeper reasoning?)

**How do we understand this from the gauge theory or QFT view?**

[image]

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147335/50583; Since there are no magnetic monopoles in the real world as far as we know, it seems to me that the choice of the sign in $q_m\mapsto \pm q_m$ is an arbitrary choice in our theorycrafting. Can you explain what you expect an argument in favor of one or the other sign to be based on?

Comment: Good question. >>what you expect an argument in favor of one or the other sign to be based on? Ans: I imagine that it will be based on the consistency of considering the $U(1)$ gauge theory with other larger structure, such as in the grand unified theory or something else (if gravity is involved).